# Is there a difference between A1435 and A1425 chargers?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, compatibility, accessories

I own a A1502 MacBook Pro Retina 13" display. It came with a 60W charger model A1435. I want to get a case for the charger, I see there are lots of accessories available for A1425 and many spare parts suppliers list A1435 and A1425 together. Are those compatible?

1. What is the actual difference between A1435 and A1425?
2. Are those compatible when it comes to their specification? Can both of them charge A1502 MacBook?
3. Are those dimensionally compatible? Can same accessories fit both models?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A1425 is the Macbook itself, the A1435 is the charger. So they are "compatible" in the sense that the accessories of the cases just add the identifier of the macbook that the charger came with.

So it is the same thing, once described by it's model number and once by the macbook that it was shipped with. You can buy accessories with either identifier and they will fit.

Comment: The A1435 charger came with my MacBook which is A1502. I'm confused... Reason why I'm asking is there is lots of accessories for A1425 charger but I can't find any for A1435, I was wondering if I order for A1425 if it would fit.

Comment: Yes, they will fit. The A1425 is one of the macbooks this charger came with, yours will fit as well.